# JPA, embeddable class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I want to add an embedded relationship to an entity class.

In my database I have table `protein`:

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| PID               | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| uniprot_UniprotAC | char(6)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |

| comment           | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |

+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and table `benchmark`:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ba_type         | varchar(255)                   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| target          | int(11) unsigned               | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |

| rec_diluation   | varchar(255)                   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| comment         | text                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In `benchmark` the field target is a foreign key for the `protein` table

I already have an entity called `SupProtein` from the protein table which works fine.

Now I want to add an embedded relation to a `Benchmark` class.

This is my benchmark class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Benchmark implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="ba_type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="comment")
    private String comment;
    @Column(name="recDilution")
    private String recDilution;  

    public Benchmark(){

    }

        public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getRecDilution() {
        return recDilution;
    }

    public void setRecDilution(String recDilution) {
        this.recDilution = recDilution;
    }

}
```

And in my entityt class `SupProtein` I add:

```
@Embedded
private Benchmark benchmark;
```

But when I try to build I get the following error:

```
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7246] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The Entity class [class SupEntity.SupProtein] has an embedded attribute [benchmark] of type [class Benchmark] which is NOT an Embeddable class. Probable reason: missing @Embeddable or missing <embeddable> in orm.xml if metadata-complete = true
```

I have not created any ORM.xml file, and can not find one anywhere. Do I need a orm.xml file to create embeddable relationships or what could be my problem?

Comment: You're probably not using the Benchmark class you think you're using. But Embeddable is not the right thing to use. You should have a OneToOne association instead. The fields of benchmarks are not embedded in the same table as the fields of protein.

Comment: Can I really use OneToOne association, doesn't that mean that I have to make benchmark an entity? And don't entities have to have an id, and that the table corresponding to the entity has to have a primary key? (which the benchmarktable doesn't have) What do you mean by "The fields of benchmarks are not embedded in the same table as the fields of protein."?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to add an embedded relation to a Benchmark class.

I think you have wrong concept:

> The @Embedded annotation is used to specify a persistent field or
>   property of an entity whose value is an instance of an embeddable
>   class. By default, column definitions specified in the @Embeddable
>   class apply to the table of the owning entity

Embedded classes are NOT entities, and are not in a table.
If **benchmark** is a table you must use @Entity annotation on the class.
Use embeddable only when some attributes of a class can be treated as an object.

Do I need a orm.xml file to create embeddable relationships or what could be my problem?
No, orm.xml is not required and is not for that purpose.

If you want to have a relationship between classes you should use @OneToOne , @OneToMany depending on the cardinality of your relationship

Comment: But in the benchmark table there is no primary key, and to me it seems I need an id field in the class in order to make it an entity. That is why I thaught I needed to make it an Embeddable class instead of an entity.